# CodeIgniter 2.1.0 Session problems

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, authentication

I have a problem with the CodeIgniter Session() Class, whereas I get errors when a user logs out. The problem is that I have a User HTML block on the Header of the page where his Avatar and info is presented. The problem is when I do this in my Logout Controller:

```
if ($this->session->userdata('is_logged_in') == 1) {
    $data['logged_in'] = TRUE;

    $this->session->sess_destroy();
}

$this->output->set_header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate");
$this->output->set_header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0");
$this->output->set_header("Pragma: no-cache");
```

.. and then in my HTML View I ask this:

```
<?php
    if ($this->session->userdata('is_logged_in') == 1) {
        // Output HTML
    }
?>
```

.. but it generates errors for all the session variables its missing.

So my question; why does 'is_logged_in' still exist when it is checked, but the rest of data is gone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bug in CI 2.1.0 that if you call `$this->session->sess_destroy()`, it doesn't unset the userdata.

The pull-request fixing the issue can be found here: https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/pull/1323.

The fix is very trivial.  You have to change the file `system\libraries\Session.php`.  You have to add the following line at the end of the function `sess_destroy()`:

```
// Kill session data
$this->userdata = array();
```

So `sess_destroy()`looks like this:

```
/**
 * Destroy the current session
 *
 * @return  void
 */
public function sess_destroy()
{
    // Kill the session DB row
    if ($this->sess_use_database === TRUE && isset($this->userdata['session_id']))
    {
        $this->CI->db->where('session_id', $this->userdata['session_id']);
        $this->CI->db->delete($this->sess_table_name);
    }

    // Kill the cookie
    setcookie(
            $this->sess_cookie_name,
            addslashes(serialize(array())),
            ($this->now - 31500000),
            $this->cookie_path,
            $this->cookie_domain,
            0
        );

    // Kill session data
    $this->userdata = array();
}
```

Comment: I figured something like that :P. That workaround did the trick, thanks :)